# Server load is spiking from 2 to 250

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'am using Wordpress 2.9.
Webserver 8GB from Hostgator.

I'am fighting with this problem for long time but still can not find the solution. Php switched to run as an apache module, Php 5 in DSO, Apache suEXEC, eaccelerator installed, but this configuration started making huge server load on server.

Server load spiking from 1 to 250 (4 cpus) and server stops, after period of time its back again and stops in about 10 minutes. It started happening when hostgator support team installed eaccelerator on server. What can make this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, turning off eaccelerator would be a good first step, to confirm that it is, in fact, the cause of the problem.  If that is the problem, time to break out the profiler, otherwise [analyse the system behaviour to identify the true cause of the problem](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/development/HuntingThePerformanceWumpus).

Comment: I turned off eaccelerator and switched php to fcgi it helped for about an hour and server locked again. Now i switched it to DSO and sever load is being about 4-9% (4 cpus). Is there any way to handle traffic problems on linux? Webserver starts having problems once there is traffic on website or once cache is being clened up.

Comment: Sure there's plenty of ways to do it, I do it for customers regularly.  Unfortunately, beyond the detailed instructions I gave in the article I linked to in my answer, my actions tend to be very... instinctual, I guess I'd call it, and hard to describe.  One of the many, many reasons you should engage the services of someone who knows what they're doing.  If this site is so traffic-heavy it requires a solid optimisation, then presumably there's enough budget to get someone who knows what they're doing to make it work right.

Comment: womble Are you an expert in Linux? Can you maybe leave me your contacts? MSN, icq, email, skype, telephone number.
I need someone who can take a look at this server and fix the problem.

Comment: I think I could be considered to know what I'm doing, but I don't do independent consulting work.

Comment: I understand that. We can discuss this, i understand that this is not for free. Let me know.